# Return first match with pattern

Tags: regex, grafana

I have a regex that should matches `doc03test1`

Test string: `doc10test2.prdoc10.com`

Regex: `(doc?\d{2,2})(test?\d{1,1})?`

Is this correct?

Comment: Did you try your regex? What is the problem?

Comment: Why do you have `?` after `doc` and `test`? That means it will match either `doc` or `do`, and `tes` or `test`. Is that what you want?

Comment: Oh no. That is not what I want. I want to match `doc` followed by two numbers and then match `test` and then one number. But there is another `doc` that I do not want to match.

Comment: What language are you using? In most languages, a regexp only returns the first match, unless you do something extra. In PHP you have to use `preg_match_all()`, in Python you have to use `re.findall()`, in JavaScript you have to use the `g` modifier.

Comment: I am using this regex in a Grafana dashboard.

Comment: So, are you using a Lucene regex engine? Then your pattern is not correct. Use `doc[0-9]{2}(test[0-9])?` or `doc[0-9]{2}(test[0-9])?.*`

Comment: `(doc\d{2,2}test\d{1,1})` worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description in the comment it can be done pretty simply:

I want to match doc: doc

followed by two numbers: \d{2}

and then match test: test

and then one number: \d

But there is another doc that I do not want to match: I added ^ to the start and $ to the end

^ represents the start of the string, it should start at doc
$ represents the end of the string, it should end as soon as we do the last digit

```
^doc\d{2}test\d$
```

https://regex101.com/r/nfB3nR/4